# Delete a row in excel .xlsx using Java

Tags: java, excel

I'm trying to remove a row in a excel sheet using java.

But my code isn't removing anything.

This is my code for removing the last row.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final String filepath = "data-DB.xlsx";
        File workbookFile = new File(filepath);
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(workbookFile);
        Workbook database = WorkbookFactory.create(in);
        Sheet sheet = database.getSheet("Users");
        int lastRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
        Row row = sheet.getRow(lastRow);
        sheet.removeRow(row);
    }
}
```

This line should get the row

```
Row row = sheet.getRow(lastRow);
```

This should remove the row.

```
sheet.removeRow(row);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `getLastRowNum` says :

> Gets the last row on the sheet Note: rows which had content before and
> were set to empty later might still be counted as rows by Excel and
> Apache POI, so the result of this method will include such rows and
> thus the returned value might be higher than expected!

So most probably you'll get getting a row number which is empty already and you are trying to remove that, and you'r seeing that `removeRow` is not working.
Print or debug the value of `lastRow` to fix the error

Comment: printing lastRow is giving me 13, and I have 14 rows in the excel sheet.
I get the same error if I do `Row row = sheet.getRow(5);` which is a line that I know exists

Comment: One more check in line `Row row = sheet.getRow(lastRow);` to see if `row` is not null.

Comment: Printing row givs me `<<xml-fragment r="14" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac" xmlns:xr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2014/revision" xmlns:xr2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2015/revision2" xmlns:xr3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2016/revision3" xmlns:main="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">`

Comment: `<main:c r="A14" t="s">
    <main:v>41</main:v>
  </main:c>
  <main:c r="B14" t="s">
    <main:v>42</main:v>
  </main:c>
  <main:c r="C14" t="s">
    <main:v>43</main:v>
  </main:c>
</xml-fragment>`

Comment: r="14" suggestes the row object is for 14th logical row which is empty. Try reducing value of variable `lastRow` by one in line `Row row = sheet.getRow(lastRow);`

Comment: `Row row = sheet.getRow(lastRow - 1);` but the line is still not deleted.
Gets r="13" when printing `row`

Comment: Either `sheet.removeRow(row);`  is not working , it is less chance. Would be a good idea to check if user under whom code is run has edit permission on file.